# How to share page link using mail?

Tags: javascript

I want to share a page link using mail. If I click on the mail it should pop up a window where I want: from address, to address and link. How can I do this?

Comment: Why have you included this link in your most recent three questions? Are you a spammer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal `mailto:` link and pass the parameters.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=From%20My%20Site&body=This%20is%20the%20body!">Mail Me</a>
```

This will send a mail with the following:

> **Subject:** From My Site
>
> **Message:** This is the body!